# How to get ISS trajectory information after spaceflight.nasa.gov has been taken offline?

Tags: iss, orbit

The [nasa spaceflight website](https://spaceflight.nasa.gov/realdata/sightings/SSapplications/Post/JavaSSOP/orbit/ISS/SVPOST.html) states that it will soon shut down.
I don't know how long this disclaimer has been there so maybe this is nothing to worry about...
In any case, which different ways do exist to get real-time data of the ISS-trajectory?

Comment: Wow, that's horrible news. The shuttle image and video archive there was unmatched at one time. (Although it has been link-rotting for years) It looks like the page was modified October 19th.  Guess when I get back home, I'm gonna have to get scraping.

Answer (score 4):

They state:

> Links to the OEMs and more details to follow.

Which hopefully means those will be posted before the page is taken down.

If not, [JPL Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi) can provide ephemerides for the ISS.
Its interface has a bit of a learning curve, so it may be a good idea to start playing with it now, in case you have a regular need for ISS trajectory data. Lots of other data is available through Horizons, so learning to use it is time well spent.

Comment: cool, telnet-interface sounds like fun